# Updating a CircularButton in a custom Fragment created with FragmentGridPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, wear-os

I have a wearable app that has a couple of fragments created with FragmentGridPagerAdapter. One of the fragments has a couple of CircularButtons and I want to update the backcolor of the button when a message is received from handheld phone. I have no problems in receiving the message. However, button's color (or anything in UI) doesn't update. Do you know how can I fix this?

```
public class UIPageAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {
private final Context mContext;
MainControlFragment[] mainControlFragments;
private List mRows;
uiChangeListener mUIChangeListener = new uiChangeListener();


public UIPageAdapter(Context ctx, FragmentManager fm) {


    super(fm);

    Log.i("pageAdapter", "constructor");
    mContext = ctx;
    mainControlFragments = new MainControlFragment[2];
    mainControlFragments[0] = new MainControlFragment();
    mainControlFragments[1] = new MainControlFragment();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).registerReceiver(mUIChangeListener,new IntentFilter(Constants.BROADCAST_CONTROL_HOME));
}

@Override
public Fragment getFragment(int row, int col) {

Log.i("PageAdapter","Fragment #" + col +"is asked");

    return mainControlFragments[col];

}

public void changeStatus(int button, boolean status) {
    mainControlFragments[0].setStatus(button,status);

 //   notifyDataSetChanged();

}


public class uiChangeListener extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String act = intent.getAction();

            if (act == Constants.BROADCAST_CONTROL_HOME) {

                int key =  intent.getIntExtra(Constants.CONTROL_HOME_KEY,-1);
                String command = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.CONTROL_HOME_COMMAND);
                changeStatus(key,command.equals("on"));
            }
    }
}


@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount(int i) {
    return 2;
}

    }
```

Basically when a message received from the handheld device a WearableListener class broadcasts an update message to the UIPageAdapter
This is the listener class

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService
 {

    String tag = "ListenerService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {


            final String message = (new String(messageEvent.getData()));
        Log.i(tag,message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_CONTROL_HOME)
                    .putExtra(Constants.CONTROL_HOME_KEY, messageEvent.getPath())
                    .putExtra(Constants.CONTROL_HOME_COMMAND,Integer.parseInt(message.substring(1)))
                    .putExtra("caller",tag));

        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(tag, "onCreate");
    }

}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="smartstuff.com.tr.myautomationtool" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="false" />

        <service android:name=".ListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Finally the custom fragment

```
public class MainControlFragment extends Fragment{
  ViewGroup container;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("controlFragment","create");
        this.container = container;
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_control, container, false);

    }

    public void setStatus(int button, boolean status) {
        Log.i("controlFragment",button + " "+ status);
        CircularButton[] btns = new CircularButton[4];
        btns[0] = (CircularButton) container.findViewById(R.id.cbtnFront);
        btns[1] = (CircularButton) container.findViewById(R.id.cbtnBack);
        btns[2] = (CircularButton) container.findViewById(R.id.cbtnBed);
        btns[3] = (CircularButton) container.findViewById(R.id.cbtnCoffee);
        btns[button].setColor(status?Color.BLACK:Color.RED);


    }
}
```

I also tried the notifyDataSetChanged(); method in UIPageAdapter however it it only calls onCreateView method in fragment. Any help is appreciated

Comment: any screenshots to add? may help here

Comment: Hi here is a https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGL34wVIGLnUUE0WWxYR2JXVGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so when you send messages, do you see any log entry corresponding to the log statement 'Log.i("controlFragment",button + " "+ status);' or you don't get that? In other words, I am asking if your issue is why the line 'btns[button].setColor(status?Color.BLACK:Color.RED);' doesn't change the color or why the local broadcast message is not delivered?

Comment: I receive the broadcast but UI doesn't update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you already resolved this but I had to add a call to `invalidate()` on the `CircularButton` after calling `setColor()`:

```
_circularButton.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), buttonColor));
_circularButton.invalidate();
```

Without the call to invalidate the UI only updated some of the time.

Comment: I didn't actually. Thanks for the reply